# PayPal 14077410 error

Tags: php, curl, paypal

I am receiving this error exception:

> PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException' with message 'error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure

from my test website.

I am using Paypal sdk  to run a simple payment (like the example that they have. In my test server locally works just fine).

I have tried various solutions that I found but no luck.

I contacted my web host provider and said that they support tls 1.2 and its a coding problem from my end.

Web server curl versions is : 7.15.5
and openssl : 0.9.8b

From what i searched online many people said that this  versions do not support tls 1.2. Did the add backwards capability ?

I also run this test but i am not sure if i am reading it correctly:

[image]
[image]

Edit :
The server finally confirmed that they are no supporting this and they also said that this server cannot be upgraded so they offered to move me to one that support this. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by endpoint? It's the first time that I try to develop something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for TLS1.2 was not added in openssl until 1.0.1, 14 Mar 2012.

https://www.openssl.org/news/changelog.html#x19

You need to update SSL on your server, and educate your host, or find a new one.

We faced this back in August (we were at 0.9.8-e-fips-rhel5); updating SSL did the trick.

Comment: I have contacted my host again and they said the are going to do some tests and answer to me. I am waiting for their response now. Thank you for your help and @Machavity help.

Answer (score 0):

To add onto what @Kkinsey said, it sounds like your host is using CentOS/RHEL 5 (which is approaching end of life). CentOS 6, while it contains the higher level of openssl, is apparently not capable of automatically negotiating TLS 1.2. CentOS 7 for some reason can.

> ## curl -v `https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp`
>
> - About to connect() to api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com port 443 (#0)
> - Trying 173.0.82.83... connected
> - Connected to api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com (173.0.82.83) port 443 (#0)
> - Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
> - CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
>     CApath: none
> - NSS error -12286
> - Closing connection #0
> - SSL connect error
>     curl: (35) SSL connect error

You have to force PHP's CURL to use TLS 1.2. Once you have upgraded your OpenSSL package (doing this on 0.9.8 WILL BREAK) you'll need to add this to your CURL request

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
```